# What function is definitely to be called in UIViewController whenever the view is shown?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

What function is definitely to be called in UIViewController whenever the view is shown in iPhone application development, including after hitting the "last view" button in a NavigationViewController?

I am getting some unsynchronized information with views using NavigationViewController. I am wondering if I can place a function call to refresh the data in the view life-cycle function that is to be called everything the view shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;` may fit your need.